# Excel grouping and subsequent ranking keeping grouping

Tags: excel, grouping, ranking

I have a file with monthly production data of factories which have specific subdivisions.

I have the subdivisions grouped under the factories.

I am trying to rank the delta of last month's difference (in descending order). However, I want the ranking of delta to be based on the main groupings, with the possibility to see the monthly delta of the subdivisions when I click on expand (they don't have to be ranked).

I have attached a sample below. Right now, the ranking is based on **ALL** the Delta's (Factory **AND** subdivision), while I only want the ranking on the Factory, with the possibility to expand/collapse the corresponding subdivision.

Does anyone know how I can manage this?

The example coded below is what I have as Table 1 right now.

Table 2 is my expected results.

The underlying formula that I am using now to try and create table 2 can be found below (so likely needs to be adjusted).

Table 1 (where sub A-C are grouped and can be hidden/shown):

```
Factory     Delta   Jan Feb
Factory 1   10  100 110
Sub A   5   50  55
Sub b   3   30  33
Sub C   2   20  22
Factory 2   -50 200 150
Sub Aa  -10 120 110
Sub Bb  -40 80  40
Factory 3   25  400 425
Sub Aaa 0   300 300
Sub Bbb 25  100 125
Factory 4   150 250 400
Sub AAAA    50  100 150
Sub BBBB    50  75  125
Sub CCCC    50  75  125
```

Table 2 (ordered required), possibility to expand and see subdivisions

```
    Factory     Delta
1   Factory 4   150
2   Factory 3   25
3   Factory 2   10
4   Factory 1   -50
```

The underlying formula for showing the proper ranking is as follows:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$15,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$15,A20),$B$2:$B$15,0),1)
```

The ranking of the second table can be found in `A20:A34`